# Exception trying to retrieve column with 'i' in the column name using ODAC in turkish

Tags: oracle, localization, odp.net, odac, turkish

I'm hitting an exception when trying to access data from an Oracle database using ODP.NET (ODAC). The code goes like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-tr");
string s = "SELECT MyString from MyTable";
var conn = new OracleConnection(connectString);
conn.Open();
var cmd = new OracleCommand(s, conn);
var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rdr.Read();
object o1 = rdr[0];
object o2 = rdr["MYSTRING"];
object o3 = rdr["MyString"];
```

the o1 and o2 assignments work OK, but the o3 assignment gives an exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Unable to find specified column in result set
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.get_Item(String columnName)
```

I'm fully aware of the "turkish I" problem. It looks to me like a bug in ODAC (it's converting the column name to upper case using the current culture rather than the invariant culture) but I haven't found anyone else reporting similar problems.

two questions:

1. is this really a bug in ODAC or am I doing something wrong?
2. If it is a bug, as a workaround can I simply convert all column names to upper case (using invariant culture) when retrieving named columns?

Comment: I've now decompiled the code and I can see where it's doing the uppercase conversion and unfortunately it is using the current culture settings, so whereas the column name returned from the server is MYSTRING, if I ask for MyString, it's actually looking for a column called MYSTRİNG (with a dotted capital I) which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to any language setting. By default column names in Oracle are all upper case. If you like to have it case sensitive, try

```
string s = "SELECT MyString AS \"MyString\" from MyTable";
```

Of course, in this case `object o2 = rdr["MYSTRING"];` will fail.

In case it is a problem with Turkish language:

`Oracle.DataAccess` does not depend on current .NET culture settings, it inherits setting from `NLS_LANG` value. Set `NLS_LANG` value properly before you start your application, for example to

```
NLS_LANG=TURKISH_TURKEY.AL32UTF8
```

You can set it either as **Environment Variable** or in Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 32 bit application on 64 bit Windows), resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 64 bit).

Another solution is to change it in Oracle session before you execute the query like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'TURKEY'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or you can use the ODP.NET **Managed** Driver, this is not NLS_LANG sensitive. It is only .NET locale sensitive (but does not support thread-based globalization), see [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/featGlobal.htm#ODPNT437)

Comment: I'm not trying to make it case insensitive, nor am I trying to store any turkish data; I'm just trying to retrieve a column from a database table by specifying the column name.

Comment: BTW thanks for the hint about the ODP.NET Managed driver - I didn't realise this existed but will definitely investigate this. Even if it has the same bug, it will be a lot easier to deploy

Comment: sorry the first comment should have read "I'm not trying to make it case sensitive"